# D7 - How to decode in a PDF file a string encoded in Base64 extracted from an XML file?

Tags: xml, base64, delphi-7, indy

I work in a D7 environment using Indy 10.0.52 components on Win10.

I receive XML files that contain attached files, encoded in Base64, in the `<Attachment>` element.

The files are extracted using the `DecodeString()` function of the `TIdDecoderMIME` component.

The extracted content is assigned to a previously created `TMemo` component, then use the `SaveToFile()` function to create a file on disk. All is ok.

Here the code:

```
var
  A,B: integer; 
  Campo,nDoc,Cart,Dato: string;
  B64: TIdDecoderMIME;
  mStr: TMemo;
  Nodo,sNod1: IXMLNode;
  // Cart->directory
  // nDoc->file name
  ...
  for A := 0 to Nodo.ChildNodes.Count-1 do begin
    Campo := Nodo.ChildNodes[A].NodeName; 
    if Campo = 'Allegati' then begin
      sNod1 := Nodo.ChildNodes[A];
      for B := 0 to sNod1.ChildNodes.Count-1 do begin
        Campo := sNod1.ChildNodes[B].NodeName;
        if Campo = 'Attachment' then begin
          if sNod1.ChildNodes[B].NodeValue <> NULL then begin
            B64 := TIdDecoderMIME.Create(FormPrinc);
            mStr := TMemo.Create(FormPrinc);
            mStr.Text := B64.DecodeString( Trim(sNod1.ChildNodes[B].NodeValue));
            mStr.Lines.SaveToFile(Cart+'\'+nDoc);
            B64.Free;
            mStr.Free;
          end;
          Break;                       
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

For some time, however, the attached files have a `.PDF` extension: the extraction routine works normally, but the file created on disk is unreadable when opened ("format error: not a pdf or corrupted"). It's necessary to change the method.

Looking at the `TIdDecoderMIME` component, it incorporates the procedure `Decode()`, which decodes a string into `FStream`, but `FStream` is not reachable.

How can I transfer the content of `FStream` to a `TMemoryStream` variable
from which to save in a `.PDF` file?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> The extracted content is assigned to a previously created `TMemo` component, then use the `SaveToFile()` function to create a file on disk

That is a *horrible* way to handle this, particularly for binary data. You should not be involving a `TMemo` at all (especially one that is not even visible to the user), you are corrupting the PDF data by decoding it into a `String`.

You need to use the `TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeStream()` method instead (which is a `class` method, so you don't need an object instance to call it. Same with `DecodeString()`). Save the output to a `TStream` of your choosing, such as a `TFileStream`, eg:

```
if sNod1.ChildNodes[B].NodeValue <> NULL then begin
  FS := TFileStream.Create(Cart+'\'+nDoc, fmCreate);
  try
    TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeStream(Trim(sNod1.ChildNodes[B].NodeValue), FS);
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or, a `TMemoryStream`:

```
if sNod1.ChildNodes[B].NodeValue <> NULL then begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeStream(Trim(sNod1.ChildNodes[B].NodeValue), MS);
    MS.Position := 0;
    MS.SaveToFile(Cart+'\'+nDoc);
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Your Indy version is VERY old, so if it doesn't have `DecodeStream()` available yet, you will have to use the non-`class` `Decode()` method instead. The internal `FStream` member is set by calling the `DecodeBegin()` method, eg:

```
if sNod1.ChildNodes[B].NodeValue <> NULL then begin
  B64 := TIdDecoderMIME.Create(nil);
  try
    FS := TFileStream.Create(Cart+'\'+nDoc, fmCreate);
    // or: MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      B64.DecodeBegin(FS{or: MS});
      B64.Decode(Trim(sNod1.ChildNodes[B].NodeValue));
      B64.DecodeEnd;
      {MS.Position := 0;
      MS.SaveToFile(Cart+'\'+nDoc);}
    finally
      FS.Free;
      // or: MS.Free;
    end;
  finally
    B64.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: (reduced code)
~
Ss3: TFileStream;
  ...
  Ss3 := TFileStream.Create(Cart+'\'+nDoc, fmCreate);
  try
    B64.DecodeBegin(Ss3);
    B64.Decode( Trim(sNod1.ChildNodes[B].NodeValue) ); 
    B64.DecodeEnd;
  finally
  ...  
~
The compiler says:
"Incompatible types: 'TIdStream' and 'TFileStream'." at B64.DecodeBegin(Ss3) 
DecodeBegin() requires a TIdStream parameter, but the passed one is of type TFileStream.
I tried to create a TIdStream memory variable, but after seeing what it includes, I think TIdStream is an intermediate class and not directly usable (has no creation procedure)

Comment: @AntonioBianca `TIdStream` no longer exists in Indy, it was removed MANY MANY YEARS ago. You are using a VERY VERY VERY old version of Indy 10 and really should [upgrade to a modern version](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/wiki/Updating-Indy). In any case, `TIdStream` was just an alias for `TStream` (`type TIdStream = TStream;`) in the `IdObjs` unit. You *should* be able to assign any `TStream` descendant to a `TIdStream` just fine. `TIdStream` only existed to handle differences in streams between Delphi and Delphi.NET, but that was later resolved with the standard `TStream`

Comment: Very very very old? Ok, but on the Indy org website the latest version is 10.0.52: where can I find the most recent one? This question is not part of this post, but I found nothing else ...

Comment: @AntonioBianca "*Very very very old?*" - EXTREMELY old, like **almost 2 decades old**. "*on the Indy org website the latest version is 10.0.52*" - no, it only *mentioned* 10.0.52, and even then it said that version is old and shouldn't be used (I have now removed that link from the site altogether). The **current** version is 10.6.2. The Indy site links to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/) that has the latest code.

Comment: 2 decades old!! (°o°) I have always referred to the Indy site: sorry... The guidelines say it is not done, but I thank you all the same for your patience. Best regard